# how to create n linear layers in pytorch when n is an argument to the function

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I have the following model:

```
class model(nn.Module):
     def __init__(self,y_dim,x_dim):
         super(model,self).__init__()
         self.x_dim = x_dim
         self.y_dim = y_dim
         self.kern = 3
         self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(y_dim,2,self.kern,padding=1)
         self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(2,4,self.kern,padding=1)
         self.conv3 = nn.Conv1d(4,4,self.kern,padding=1)
         self.conv4 = nn.Conv1d(4,y_dim,self.kern,padding=1)
         #these are the layers I want to automate
         self.lina = nn.Linear(28,28)
         self.linb = nn.Linear(28,28)
     def forward(self,x):
         x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
         x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
         x = F.relu(self.conv3(x))
         x = F.relu(self.conv4(x))
         xa = self.lina(x[:,0,:]).reshape(z.shape[0],1,z.shape[2])
         xb = self.linb(x[:,1,:]).reshape(z.shape[0],1,z.shape[2])
         return torch.cat((xa,xb),1)

model = model(2,28)
```

So, the output channels of `self.conv4` is always `y_dim`. I'd like to have `y_dim` different linear layers (which are independent) that take the output of `self.conv4`. As of now, I don't know a better way than explicitly writing the layers, as I did in the example above. However, is there a method to automate this, namely generating the linear layer object and then using it in the `forward` function appropriately?

Comment: Also: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/when-should-i-use-nn-modulelist-and-when-should-i-use-nn-sequential/5463/2